# "Application Pools" in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Do we have any similar feature to Application Pool in SQL Server? We have a dozen of databases in the SQL Server for a dozen different web apps. Once in a while, some developers would write some rediculous complex stored procedures and slow down the entire database server. If there is a way for all of my databases to be in the same pool and others in theirs so that their bad code can only use up that pool's resource and slow down that pool only, that would be perfect.

Comment: There are not multiple application pools. You might take a look at resource governor. It might apply in your situation but hard to know for sure because your question is pretty vague.

Comment: fwiw, the real issue most likely is not that the procedures are complex, it is that they are poorly written.

Comment: LOL. Sean, I was trying to be nice :-)

Comment: hehe. So maybe fixing the cause instead of a putting a band aid on effect would be a better approach? If the procedures are written properly your issue is no longer a big deal. The upside is that everyone wins this way.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to throttle resource usage (CPU, threads, RAM) by database (as-of 2008 R2) but it is possible to do this per-instance.  So, if you install several instances of SQL server, on the same machine, you can limit/throttle/allocate several resources to each instance.  2008 R2 (and up) also includes "Windows fibres" which is a lightweight pooling option.

To see all options, use SSMS, connect to a server, right-click the server instance name, choose Properties, and look at the Processors (and even Memory) tabs.

It sounds like you would have to scale-out your server (meaning: install more SQL server instances and move DBs to those instances) to isolate this traffic and take advantage of these features.

Comment: Can I assume you enver heard of the Resource Governor in SQL Server. YOu meantion 2008 R2 but hey, that was introduced in 2008.

Comment: I would not recommend the resource governor. Based on your description, it is not a good solution for you. Before you go down that road, you might want to read-up on other people's opinions of it and some of the support questions/complaints related to it. That might help you develop your own opinion of it. Start with the search in the upper-right corner: "SQL Server Resource Governor".

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, with the ressource governor.

Sadly this is not a feature supported on your totally ancient version. They started it with 2008, it is now quite capable at 2014.

You can read up on it at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866.aspx - which is the starting point in the documentation for this feature.